# Why WHERE clause can't use alias but GROUP BY clause can in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm curious about the reason why WHERE clause can't use alias but GROUP BY clause can in a sql. I found the [MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

But the statements in the MySQL documentation fail to convince me.

Renaming should occur simultaneously; otherwise, the following statement would become correct:

```
Invalid in MySQL:
SELECT id AS k, k + 1 FROM t;
```

According to MySQL documentation, since the values of `count(*)` are determined after aggregation, the alias of `count(*)` shouldn't be used by GROUP BY either.

Furthermore, renaming multiple fields should occur simultaneously, so GROUP BY shouldn't use another alias either. However, reality is the opposite:

```
Valid in MySQL:
SELECT id AS k, count(*) AS ans FROM t GROUP BY k;
```

There is a contradiction. I think the reason why WHERE can't use an alias but GROUP BY can is simply because the programmers choose to analyze the WHERE clause first, then the field list, and the GROUP BY clause last. Am I wrong?

Comment: Quite right, using it in `GROUP BY` is non-standard and not supported in many DBMSs, because `SELECT` is evaluated after `GROUP BY`. Docs for `SELECT` say: "A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: It's a MySQL-ism, not standard SQL. In standard SQL, you can't group by aliases or expressions. See https://sql-99.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapters/33.html#grouping-by-expressions

Comment: Probably only works in `MySQL`, but it definitely won't work in any other dbms.